# EditorFor ignores TemplateInfo.FieldPrefix

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I am using HtmlEditor.EditorFor() to display extended editing.

After setting the HtmlFieldPrefix of the HtmlEditor with

```
htmlHelper.ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix = "MySpecialFieldPrefix";
```

I call

```
htmlHelper.EditorFor(Expression)
```

In the View the HtmlFieldPrefix is empty, which breaks my binding for the model. I would expect it to be `"MySpecialFieldPrefix"`!

```
@Html.ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix
```

Can someone tell me why it is empty? Which HtmlHelper does EditorFor use?

---

Update:

It seems as the handling with htmlHelper seems different then (I) expected.

I don't use the HtmlHelper of the view, but create a new one (because I have to change the model). The HtmlHelper.EditorFor seems to use the HtmlHelper of the View not the one I create (Why does it do that???).

When I set the HtmlFieldPrefix for the Views-HtmlHelper the Prefix is correct.

Comment: Try `@HtmlEditorFor(m =>m.yourProperty, new ViewDataDictionary { TemplateInfo = new TemplateInfo { HtmlFieldPrefix = "MySpecialFieldPrefix" }}`

Comment: I tried it and yes it is sent to the view. Unfortunatly different than expected, because it is part of the viewbag. :-( Can I have it at ViewData?

Comment: You need to give a bit more details of what your actually trying to do here (including the real code). The `@HtmlEditorFor(m => m.someProperty)` method will correctly pass the prefix of any parent model and the fact that your trying to manually add a prefix using a hack suggests you have other problems with your design or code.

Answer (score 0):

You should pass your htmlHelper in ViewBag or ViewData and then cast it back to a variable and use @htmlHelper.xxx in your view instead of @Html.xxx

Before calling your view:

```
@{
    htmlHelper.ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix = "MySpecialFieldPrefix";
    ViewBag.HtmlHelper = htmlHelper;
}
```

In your view:

```
@{
    HtmlHelper htmlHelper = (HtmlHelper)ViewBag.HtmlHelper;
}

@htmlHelper.EditorFor(m => m.Field)
```